# Prismatic Joints for Box2d As3 won't work?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, box2d

im trying to create a moving platform in box2d using prismatic joints, all that is created is a box and no joints are apparent, what am I doing wrong? Here is my code

```
        var prismaticJoint:b2PrismaticJoint;
        ...
        {
         ...
        BodyDef.position.Set(0 / RATIO, 0 / RATIO);
        floorDef.SetAsBox(250 / RATIO, 10 / RATIO);

        fixtureDef.shape = floorDef;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.5;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.5;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0;

        movePlatformBody = PhysiVals.world.CreateBody(BodyDef);
        movePlatformBody.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);


        var prismaticJointDef:b2PrismaticJointDef = new b2PrismaticJointDef();
        prismaticJointDef.Initialize(body, movePlatformBody, movePlatformBody.GetWorldCenter(), new b2Vec2(0,1));
        prismaticJointDef.enableLimit = true;
        prismaticJointDef.enableMotor = true;
        prismaticJointDef.lowerTranslation = 0;
        prismaticJointDef.maxMotorForce = 100;
        prismaticJointDef.motorSpeed = 1;
        prismaticJointDef.upperTranslation = 270 / PhysiVals.RATIO;
        PhysiVals.world.CreateJoint(prismaticJointDef);
        //prismaticJoint = PhysiVals.world.CreateJoint(prismaticJointDef as b2JointDef) as b2PrismaticJoint;
```

I tried 2 ways of creating it in the world, I dont know which one to use. How do I create a moving platform in box2d? Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your initialize statement. Set the first parameter to the body that is going to move (the platform), set the second parameter to the static body (the world), and the third parameter will be the platforms centre.

I wrote a pretty popular tutorial on Box2D joints with an example of Prismatic Joints with source code so have a look at that too if you are still having problems 
[Tutorial](http://blog.allanbishop.com/box2d-2-1a-tutorial-part-2-joints/).

Comment: Thanks for the respones! I actually was looking at your tutorials before and was using it and others.   I tried that but it didn't work, the platform only remains static and does not move, even in debug draw there arnt any lines indicating a joint or anything, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try replacing the body that isn't meant to move (that acts as an anchor) with the body PhysiVals.world.GetGroundBody()?

Comment: Yeah, tried that, still didn't seem to work, im trying to get something to work like in [this](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/1087/12/Getting-Started-with-Box2D/Page12.html) tutorial, but I have not come close, again, the result is just a static box, I tried changing the density and and other values but it just remains static

Comment: hmm. I feel it will be something simple as from what I can see your code is looking correct. Just to clarify, the b2Body that you want to move as a platform is a dynamic type? Also, since you mentioned that you can't even see the joint in debug view make sure you have not created another b2World somehow. What happens if you make a different sort of joint? Maybe also use my tutorial source code, make the platform you want and then place it back in yours. Might help find what is going wrong.

Comment: Oh, that is what was wrong! I didnt set they type to dynamic in the body def! Thank you very much for all you did! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Allan Thanks man you saved me :) I thought that implementation in AS3 is bad. I did not put first argument to be the body of the platform. I put ground body as the first argument instead. And it was behaving so strange and I did not have idea why and documentation is scarse. Thanks again.